# How can I display the code of a specific R file in an R Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

So I have a shiny app. I want to create a new tab. And within that new tab I want to display the code in a specific R file that is located in a folder within the package.

Basic requirements is to display the R file as if it is a text file verbatim.

Enhance features would have it display text and color rendering as if reading it from RStudio or something.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/including-html-text-and-markdown-files.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by rendering the file contents as HTML inside `<pre><code>` tags...

Say your file is in `www/random_fn.R`:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(

            tabPanel("Home", sliderInput(inputId = "bins",label = "Bins", min = 0, max = 10, value = 3),
                     plotOutput("distPlot")),
            tabPanel("R Code", uiOutput("show_code")
        ))
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })

    output$show_code <- renderUI({
        raw_lines <- readLines("www/random_fn.R")
        # insert line breaks for HTML
        code_joined <- stringi::stri_join(raw_lines, collapse = "\n")

        tagList(
            tags$pre(
                tags$code(
                    HTML(code_joined)
                )
            )
        )
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Also you can use package [shinyAce](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyAce)

[image]